# Start up items removed with launchctl come back at restart

Tags: macos, launchd

I removed Citrix with launchctl but the files are all back after I restart.  How do I remove them for good?  (Regular uninstall did not work.)

Here is what I did:

```
launchctl list | grep citrix
     com.citrix.safariadapter
     com.citrix.ServiceRecords
     com.citrix.ReceiverHelper
     com.citrix.AuthManager_Mac
launchctl remove com.citrix.ServiceRecords 
launchctl remove com.citrix.AuthManager_Mac
launchctl remove com.citrix.ReceiverHelper 
launchctl remove com.citrix.safariadapter
```

When I restart, Citrix tries to start again and when I do a list, they are all back.

Comment: "Regular uninstall did not work." What qualifies as 'regular' uninstall. It uses an installer, so you can't just throw out the app, you need an uninstaller - https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-mac/install-uninstall.html

Answer (score 1):

Things to try:

- Is the service restarting on your user, or does it also reappear if you login with another user, e.g., the guest?
- Have you tried ensuring that the service is not listed in /var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/ ? If it is listen in a loginitemXXX.plist file, that is the problem.
- Otherwise, there must be another service which reinstated the ones you try to remove. So you still need to remove something else to clean it up completely.